# Wordpress database becoming huge. How to analyze and optimize it? fear of running out of memory

Tags: database, performance, memory

look at the size of my wordpress database tables:

[image: look at the size of my wordpress database tables]

are there simple ways to optimize it? I fear of running out of memory one day

maybe bad collation? how can I analyze what is eating up so much space in the posts and post meta tables?

Comment: Take a look into [WP-Sweep](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sweep/) plugin. This will probably cut your database by half!

Comment: don't see anything "huge" there.

Comment: .... you obviously should not store stats in the same DB, or even the same server, but that is not related to the size of the DB

Comment: You post tables are actually rather small, also the options table. I don't think there is any problem with that.

Comment: Yep, I agree – that's quite small

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to help reduce the amount of bloat is add a plugin that controls the number of previous revisions kept for Pages, Posts, etc (preferably one that allows for separate values for each type, such as last 5 revisions for pages and last 20 revisions for posts, or whatever.)

There are numerous plugins that handle this, check around https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/revision+control/ and similar

Answer (score 1):

The thing i do for this to minimize and optimize the database is by adding a two line of code on config.php

```
define('AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 300 ); //seconds (default is 60)
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 5 ); //alter number of post revisions kept.
```

- the constant ‘AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL’ represents the delay between the two autosaves in seconds.
- the constant ‘WP_POST_REVISIONS’ a record of each saved draft or published update.

you can also use [wp-optimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/) plugin to optimize your Database and cleaning your WordPress database so that it runs at maximum efficiency.